# Information about Stack Exchange sanitizer for Markdown (XSS)

Tags: discussion, markdown, xss

How does Stack Exchange sanitize the user's text to prevent [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) injections?

I've seen that if I write: ([this is the doc about this bug](http://michelf.ca/blog/2010/markdown-and-xss/))

```
> hello <a name="n"
> href="javascript:alert('xss')">*you*</a>
```

It sanitizes the output, even the preview.

Is it possible to know how it sanitizes the text for preventing this Markdown bug?

Comment: Isn't that explained in the article you linked? *"So the conclusion is that, if you want real security, you need to filter Markdown’s output, not the input. There’s no other choice."* So, I'd assume that's exactly what SE does. But you could [peek into the code](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/).

Comment: I wonder how it can sanitize the preview, the only way (according to my link) is to use Ajax call for sanitize the input, but I don't think it uses this solution..

Comment: The preview is generated purely by JavaScript. It does not send it to the server to generate a preview then receive one back.

Comment: Yes I was sure, so the javascript markdown parser know how to prevent this vulnerability, is the javascript version open source and downloadable?

Comment: [`Markdown.Sanitizer.js`](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/Markdown.Sanitizer.js) is part of Stack Exchange's open source markdown parser, PageDown. It's not an entirely general-purpose HTML sanitizer, it requires that users use a specific HTML subset.

Comment: Could you link me the page where I can download it please?

Comment: @FezVrasta http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/

Comment: Thank you. Solved :)